# Lifespan of variable and garbage collection

Tags: c#, scope, garbage-collection

I recently started learning C# and created a basic program that contrains a class to represent a company and another one to represent employees. The `Company` class contains a method to hire an `Employee` (basically, add to a list of `Employee`s).

Here is the code for `Company`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace tutorial {
    static public class Company {
        static public List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        static public void Hire (Employee emp) {
            employees.Add(emp);
        }

        static public void ListEmployees () {
            foreach (Employee emp in employees) {
                Console.WriteLine(emp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the main program:

```
using System;

namespace tutorial {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Company.Hire(new Employee("John", "Smith", DateTime.Now));
            Company.Hire(new Employee("Jane", "Smith", DateTime.Now));
            Company.ListEmployees();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, my question is: when can the `Employee`s created be deleted/garbage collected?

The person in charge of the C# class tells me this may happen as soon as the `Hire` method returns. This means `ListEmployees` may read an empty list.

However, `ListEmployees` works as expected. Moreover, my understanding is that reference counting is used, so the `Employee`s won't be deleted as long as the `Company` static class exists (that is, as long as the program is running).

Could anyone tell me how memory management works here? Am I wrong in my understanding of reference counting?

Comment: You just learned C# and one of your first concerns is the garbage collector? The purpose of it is that you don't have to care about such things (most times).

Comment: If that's what they're being taught then that's what they're being taught. If what they're being taught is wrong as well, then all the more reason to correct it now while its fresh, even if it should be largely irrelevant knowledge at this point in learning C#.

Comment: And no, that list will not be eligible for garbage collection as long as it is still referenced by that static member, until the appdomain is unloaded (typically because the process is terminating). Same goes for employees *in* that list, they're no more eligible for garbage collection than the list, as long as they are in that list.

Comment: And .NET doesn't use reference counting (outside of some COM interop stuff)

Comment: What is more important than how the GC works under the hood is that you should be careful with `static`. Every company of the world now has the same employees. Well, there is only one company

Comment: A simplified description of how the garbage collection (GC) works in .NET is that it uses static fields, and local variables of executing methods to *know* what is currently being referenced, and then tracks out from there, so if a static field contains a reference to something that contains a reference to something else, that "something else" is not eligible for garbage collection. So basically it determines if an object on the heap is being referenced (indirectly) by something that is static or a local variable. There's a lot more details than that, but it should suffice as a start.

Comment: [Straight from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references) *The garbage collector cannot collect an object in use by an application while the application's code can reach that object. The application is said to have a strong reference to the object.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/):

> When the garbage collector performs a collection, it checks for objects in the managed heap that are no longer being used by the application and performs the necessary operations to reclaim their memory.

To answer your question the `Employees` will be garbage collected when the application stops because your class is declared as `static`. However, if you remove the static from the class but not from the field your field will still have the same lifespan as the application. You need not only remove the static from the class but also from the field itself.

Behind the scenes Microsoft for implementing the `static` keyword Microsoft uses the [Singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). Thus making your class live for as long as the application is running.

If you wish to avoid this you can make your class non static in this case the `Employees` will be garbage collected when an instance of the `Company` class is no longer used. I.e.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Company comp = new Company();

        //Somecode
    }

}
class Company
{
    public List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    public void Hire(Employee emp)
    {
        employees.Add(emp);
    }

    public void ListEmployees()
    {
        foreach (Employee emp in employees)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(emp);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example when the `Main` method is invoked it will create an instance of the Company class and the lifetime of that instance is the scope of the `Main` method. Once the method is exited the `comp` variable will be eligible for garbage collection.

I recommend for you to read the whole documentation for GC(garbage collection) because Microsoft have explained really good how things work.

Comment: Note that it is actually because the *field* is static, not directly because the *class* is static (though a static class implies static fields). You can make the class non-static and still have a static field and the same would apply.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yeah that it correct it slipped my mind.